# Cannot create observable from Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.readFile) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I am trying to use [rxjs 5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS) to write a Node.js server in TypeScript, but I hit an error when converting `fs.readFile` to its rxjs form. I expect the following code would work in TypeScript

```
// This is a JavaScript example from the official documentation. It should
// also work at the TypeScript envrionment.

import * as fs from 'fs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

let readFileAsObservable = Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.readFile);

// This is the line that throws the error.
let result = readFileAsObservable('./roadNames.txt', 'utf8');

result.subscribe(x => console.log(x), e => console.error(e));
```

However, my editor reports a TypeScript error when I add the second parameter `'utf-8'`

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

I try to find a guide on how to use the `fs.readFile()` in rxjs and TypeScript but there isn't much luck.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`bindCallback` and `bindNodeCallback` can be tricky with TypeScript, as it all depends upon how TypeScript infers the function parameters.

There is likely a better way, but this is what I do to see exactly what is being inferred: assign the observable to something totally incompatible and look closely at the effected error. For example, this:

```
const n: number = Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.readFile);
```

will effect this error:

```
Type '(v1: string) => Observable<Buffer>' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

So it's obvious that TypeScript is matching the path-only overload of `readFile`.

In situations like this, I often use an arrow function to specify exactly which overload I want to use. For example, this:

```
const n: number = Observable.bindNodeCallback((
  path: string,
  encoding: string,
  callback: (error: Error, buffer: Buffer) => void
) => fs.readFile(path, encoding, callback));
```

will effect this error:

```
Type '(v1: string, v2: string) => Observable<Buffer>' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

So it's now matching the desired overload and the following will work:

```
let readFileAsObservable = Observable.bindNodeCallback((
  path: string,
  encoding: string,
  callback: (error: Error, buffer: Buffer) => void
) => fs.readFile(path, encoding, callback));

let result = readFileAsObservable('./package.json', 'utf8');
result.subscribe(
  buffer => console.log(buffer.toString()),
  error => console.error(error)
);
```

Comment: Nice way to enforce the function overloading. Thanks!

Comment: Should I consider this as a result of the nature of TypeScript (definitely typed), or a design flaw of rxjs?

Comment: From my point of view, it's not a design flaw. If the function has overloads, there's simply no way it can guess which one you want. I think TypeScript does a pretty good job inferring the parameter types. The other benefit of using an arrow function is that you can avoid using `bind` when the method needs to be called on a particular context. `bind` returns `any` and then TypeScript inferences are well and truly messed with.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest i haven't found a solution, but in order to make it work, i cast it to a function.

```
(<Function>Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.readFile))('./file.txt', 'utf8').subscribe();
```