# Unable to use bindNodeCallback

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, auth0

I'm trying this:

`return Observable.bindNodeCallback(this.webAuth.client.userInfo)(this.accessToken);`

I'm trying to create an observable out of the Auth0 userInfo function so that I can use it in canActivate in AuthGuard.

But I'm getting this error:

`TS2346:Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

The library function above is:

```js
Authentication.prototype.userInfo = function(accessToken, cb) {
  var url;
  assert.check(accessToken, {
    type: 'string',
    message: 'accessToken parameter is not valid'
  });
  assert.check(cb, {
    type: 'function',
    message: 'cb parameter is not valid'
  });
  url = urljoin(this.baseOptions.rootUrl, 'userinfo');
  return this.request
    .get(url)
    .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken)
    .end(responseHandler(cb, {
      ignoreCasing: true
    }));
};
```

Comment: Have you checked: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback?

Comment: Yes of course, and I believe I'm following the instructions correctly!

Comment: Absolutely, it is.

Comment: You mean acessToken is an error object?

Comment: Ohhh!! I thought the first parameter in the *callback* function has to be an error object :-(

Comment: I think you are right, my bad :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144699/discussion-between-sammy-and-echonax).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43463287/6680611) explains how I solve problems with `bindNodeCallback`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the **exact same problem**. Eventually, instead of using `bindNodeCallback()`, I [discovered you can just wrap the entire call to `userInfo()` in `Observable.create()`](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/issues/472#issuecomment-316609794) like this (NOTE: the outer `userInfo()` function is part of my `AuthProvider` class):

```
userInfo = (token: string): Observable<User> => Observable.create(observer => {
  this.auth0.client.userInfo(token, (err: any, user: User) => {
    if (err) {
      observer.error(err);
    }
    observer.next(user);
    observer.complete();
  });
});
```

#### Testing (with Jest)

In case you want a unit test for the code above, I use the amazing [`rxjs-marbles` library](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles) developed by  [@cartant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6680611/cartant) (who responded in the comments above). Here are some snippets from the relevant parts of my test:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { marbles } from 'rxjs-marbles/jest'; // <-- add /jest here to level-up!
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { StoreModule, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AuthProvider } from './auth'; // my authentication service

// Here's a mock for the relevant bits of the Auth0 library
jest.mock('auth0-js', () => ({
  WebAuth: options => ({
    client: {
      userInfo: (token, cb) => { 
        if ( "error" === token ) {
          cb(new Error("Profile error!"), null);
        } else {
          cb(null, {name: "Alice"}); 
        }
      }
    }
  })
}));

describe("Auth0.WebAuth.client", () => {
  let auth: AuthProvider;
  let store: Store<any>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:   [ StoreModule.forRoot({}) ],
      providers: [ AuthProvider ]
    });
    store = TestBed.get(Store);
    spyOn(store, 'pipe');
    auth = TestBed.get(AuthProvider);
  });

  it("should return Observable<User> when calling userInfo()", marbles((m) => {
    const user = { name: "Alice" }; // must match mocked value above
    const source = m.cold("--a", { a: "dummy-access-token" });
    const target = m.cold("--b", { b: user });
    const profile = source.flatMap(auth.userInfo);

    m.expect(profile).toBeObservable(target);
 }));

  it("throw Error on fail when calling userInfo()", marbles((m) => {
    const err = new Error("Profile error!"); // must match mocked value above
    const source = m.cold("--a", { a: "error" }); // this value triggers mock error
    const target = m.cold("--#", null, err);
    const profile = source.flatMap(auth.userInfo);

    m.expect(profile).toBeObservable(target);
  }));
});
```

Some pitfalls that I encountered:

- Make sure you use **`flatMap()`** in your tests! I was hung up on that FOREVER
- I was new to [marble testing](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.2/doc/writing-marble-tests.md) and I had to [read the manual](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles) MANY times over before I really got the hang of what was going on

Answer (score 2):

I know its an old thread but I've been able to make my auth0 userInfo method to use bindNodeCallback.

Here's my solution if it can help someone :

```
// must use the bind() method to change scope of "this" inside the userInfo function
private _userInfo$ = bindNodeCallback(this._Auth0.client.userInfo.bind(this._Auth0.client));

// Get user information
public getUserInfo$() : Observable<any>{

  return this.token$.pipe(
    switchMap(token => this._userInfo$(token))
  );

}

// Check if users email is verified
public checkEmailVerified$() : Observable<boolean>{

  return this.token$.pipe(
    switchMap(token => this._userInfo$(token)),
    map(userInfo => userInfo.email_verified )
  );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the original method **wants to access** the `this` keyword for accessing internal properties of the Auth0 Client. You must **bind this client**, when you want to wrap its method to an `Observable` instance. Here is an example:

```
const userInfo = Observable.bindNodeCallback(this.webAuth.client.userInfo);
userInfo.call(this, this.accessToken);
// or
userInfo.bind(this)(this.accessToken);
```

You can use the response as an Observable afterall.

Comment: good tip, it made me advance in my problem resolution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by explicitly defining the parameters, like so:

```
const fetchProfile$ = Observable.bindNodeCallback((
  accessToken: string,
  callback: Auth0Callback<Auth0UserProfile>
) => this.auth0.client.userInfo(accessToken, callback));

return fetchProfile$(accessToken);
```