# RXJS ^5.3.0 with AWS JS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm trying to add a RxJS [Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) to [s3.upload()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property), in AWS JS SDK. Following is my code. 
Note that I'm using RXJS version ^5.3.0.

```
const s3Config = {
        Key: logoName,
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Body: files[0],
        ACL: 'public-read'
      };

      const s3Upload = s3.upload(s3Config);
      const upload$ = Observable.bindNodeCallback(s3Upload.send, s3Upload);
      upload$.subscribe(
        (value) => console.dir('Yeah !' + value),
        (err) => console.dir(err)
      );
```

How can I bind the Observable and S3.upload method? Please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bindNodeCallback` returns a function that returns an observable. And that function should be passed each of the non-callback arguments that would usually be passed to the bound function.

Also, it's quite likely that you will need to use `bind` to ensure that the `upload` method is bound to `s3`.

I would do it like this:

```
const upload = Observable.bindNodeCallback(s3.upload.bind(s3))

const upload$ = upload({
  Key: logoName,
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Body: files[0],
  ACL: 'public-read'
});

upload$.subscribe(
  data => console.dir(data),
  err => console.dir(err)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just wanted to know, I'm getting a typescript validation error near const upload$ = upload({
  Key: logoName,
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Body: files[0],
  ACL: 'public-read'
}); saying error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. Is there a way to avaoid this TS validation error ?

Comment: Yeah. I didn't mention it because I thought you were just using JavaScript. With TypeScript, the simplest solution is to use an arrow function and explicitly specify the parameter types. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43463287/6680611

Comment: You might be pleased to know that the typings for `bindNodeCallback` have been improved in RxJS v6 and the types can be inferred without using an arrow function. And if you install `rxjs` and `rxjs-compat` you should be able to use v6 with no code changes.

Comment: Actually, because you need to bind a method to a context, I think the arrow function will still the best option. IIRC, TypeScript still has some way to go to support type inference when using `bind`.